# Difference between type-graphql field type "Int" and "Number"

Tags: typescript, graphql

What's the difference between type-graphql types Int and Number?
I want to use plain integers as my graphql arguments(eg. 1 and not "1" or 1.0).

```
@GQL.Field(type => Number)
```

Also, what i have observed is when i set argument type as "Number", The schema that appears in graphql-playground shows those arguments type as float.

```
@GQL.Mutation(returns => Booking)
public async addBooking(
@GQL.Arg("user") user: number,
@GQL.Arg("bookingType") bookingType: number,
@GQL.Arg("start") start: Date,
@GQL.Arg("end") end: Date,
@GQL.Arg("bookingPackage", { nullable: true }) bookingPackage?: number,
@GQL.Arg("bookingAddons", type  => [ Number, ], { nullable: true, }) bookingAddons?: number[],
@GQL.Arg("payment", { nullable: true }) payment?: number
) {

let booking = new Booking()
booking.user = user
booking.bookingType = bookingType
booking.start = start
booking.end = end
if (bookingPackage) booking.bookingPackage = bookingPackage
if (bookingAddons) booking.bookingAddons = bookingAddons
if (payment) booking.payment = payment

await booking.save()
return booking
}
```

And the Schema that appears in graphql-playground:

```
addBooking(
payment: Float
bookingAddons: [Float!]
bookingPackage: Float
end: DateTime!
start: DateTime!
bookingType: Float!
user: Float!
): Booking!
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://typegraphql.com/docs/scalars.html#aliases

> JavaScript `Number` will become `GraphQLFloat` in the schema automatically

That's because `number` in JS is represented as a double, so Number = Float.
If you need an int, use `Int`.